# Displaying a bootstrap dropup when the textarea is at the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, bootstrap-typeahead

I am trying to use the `typeahead.js` for displaying a few names. I have a textarea at the bottom of my page and wanted to display the menu, above the textarea.
I have referred [@koala_dev response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493618/changing-the-look-of-the-bootstrap-typeahead) which perfectly suits my implementation.

As per the bootstrap [dropup documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-dropup), a div wrapper with class dropup is required on top of the `<ul>` element of the typeahead output.

I have used `bootstrap.min.css`. Below is typeahead output after the textarea element :

```
<textarea class="form-control" ng-model="ctrl.users" id="users" placeholder="Type a name" rows="2" mentionuser></textarea>
  <ul class="typeahead dropdown-menu">
    <li data-value="rohit" class="active">
      <a href="#"><span class="mention_username"> <strong>r</strong>ohit</span></a>
    </li>
    <li data-value="alpha">
      <a href="#"><span class="mention_username"> alpha</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

[image: Image for ref, the bar is at the bottom of the page]

**Note:** All I want is to display a popup, by either wrapping a `div` onto the result of typeahead `ul` element, if so then how to do it. Or by editing the css, have put in a lot of effort but the classes are not getting properly fit